# ZFS (on Linux): zfs import cannot import online pool

Tags: zfs, zfsonlinux

I have a pool that cannot be imported even though it is detected and is online.

```
$ zpool import -d /dev/disk/by-id
  pool: threetb
    id: 10173957064206389394
 state: ONLINE
action: The pool can be imported using its name or numeric identifier.
config:

    threetb                                       ONLINE
      raidz1-0                                    ONLINE
        ata-WDC_WD30EFRX-68AX9N0_WD-WMC1T3208338  ONLINE
        ata-WDC_WD30EFRX-68AX9N0_WD-WMC1T3208543  ONLINE
        ata-WDC_WD30EFRX-68AX9N0_WD-WMC1T3218685  ONLINE
        ata-WDC_WD30EFRX-68AX9N0_WD-WMC1T3295168  ONLINE
```

But when I try to import it, it cannot be found:

```
$ zpool import -f threetb
cannot import 'threetb': no such pool available
```

This happened after a reboot. Other pools import fine.

Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: Did you try `zpool import -d /dev/disk/by-id threetb`?

Comment: Thank you Thomas! That was fast and did the trick. But why?

Comment: Normally `zpool import` searches `/dev/dsk` for import candiates and should pick up the right `/dev/sd*` devices for the pool. Then with `zpool list -v` also the `/dev/sd*` names are shown. Not sure why this did not work.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Thomas blazingly fast answer I was able to import the pool by combining the device scanning with the import:

```
$ zpool import -d /dev/disk/by-id threetb
```